# React: How to call a function from another file?

Tags: reactjs

I have tried to separate a function to another file, and call it in `useEffect()`. Here is my code.

```
ReadCookie.js

import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import { AuthContext } from '../App';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export const ReadCookie = () => {
    const {setAuthenticated} = useContext(AuthContext);
    const history = useHistory();
    let user = false;
    if(user = Cookies.get("user")){
        history.push('/Homepage');
        setAuthenticated(true);
    }else{
        history.push('/');
    }
}
```

Then I call it to `Login.js` by using `useEffect`like this

```
import {ReadCookie} from './ReadCookie' 

useEffect(() => {
    ReadCookie()
},[]);
```

When I run it, it shows error in my web page like this

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a hook from outside the scope of a React function.
You could use a custom hook that reads your cookie data.

```
function useCookie(cookieName) {
   const [cookieValue, setCookValue] = React.useState(null)

   React.useEffect(() => {
       setCookieValue(ReadCookie())
   }, [])

   return cookieValue;
}
```

`Login.js`

```
function Login() {
   const cookieValue = useCookie('myCookieName');
   // here you can get cookieValue.
}
```

Comment: Isn't `useState` and `useEffect` redundant inside `useCookie`? What's the point of using it if the cookie is basically returned

Comment: I agree with your opinion. He wants to use `useEffect` with it the Read cookie function. Maybe there's an API call there somewhere inside the `useEffect`. That's my assumption.